# Access enclosing "with" statement implicitly

Tags: python, stack-trace, with-statement, inspect

I am working on something like a logging component and I want to use it like this:

```
with logging.Log(context='A', message='msg1') # with1
    do_stuff()
```

As you can see Log implements a with statement context manager. Furthermore Log stores `context` as member variable. Let's say I implement `do_stuff` as follows:

```
def do_stuff():
    with logging.Log(message='msg2') # with2
        do_other_stuff()
```

That means "with2" is called within "with1".

Question is, is there a way to access the member of "with1"? I toyed around with `inspect` but no luck so far. I know I could assign Log to a variable and pass it around. I don't want to do this because it will clutter a lot of code. Any idea?

I would like to reuse the `context`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
with logging.Log(context='A', message='msg1') as outer:
    do_stuff(outer)

def do_stuff(outer):
    with logging.Log(message='msg2'):
        print(outer.context, outer.message)
        do_other_stuff()
```

Comment: Yes I know this would work. That's what I meant with "I could assign Log to a variable and pass it around". This would clutter a lot of code since there is a lot of nested functions...

Comment: You could poke around in locals() and globals(), but I think trying to access unnamed variables is going to be messier then just passing the parameter (just my $0.02).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but only with global or near-global state, and it can get kind of messy:

```
# Thread-unsafe version
class Log(...):
    logger_stack = []
    def __enter__(self):
        Log.logger_stack.append(self)
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        Log.logger_stack.pop()
```

This lets loggers access loggers from other active `with` statements, but you can't use them in separate threads at the same time safely. Thread-local storage can fix the thread-safety problems... sort of:

```
# Thread-safeish version
class Log(...):
    thread_local = threading.local()
    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            Log.thread_local.logger_stack.append(self)
        except AttributeError:
            Log.thread_local.logger_stack = [self]
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        Log.thread_local.logger_stack.pop()
```

Now different threads won't see or interfere with each other's logging context. This prevents some bugs, but it also means that if you do something like

```
with logging.Log(...):
    delegate_to_another_thread()
```

the work that happens in the other thread won't see the first thread's logging context.